# Why is the Null terminator considered 1 character in string length when you have to type 2 characters the "\" and the "0"

Tags: null, character

In C++, Why is the Null terminator considered 1 character in string length when you have to type 2 characters the "backslash" and the "0". (so wouldn't that be 2 bytes not 1?) I am curious what is happening 'under the hood' since in the windows character map I cannot find a single \0 character that is combined into 1 character. (the fact that when I typed the backslash+0 and then previewed this post the backslash didn't draw seems to indicate that the backslash has some sort of special significance that makes it not 'count' as a character. And for that matter how then how do you printf backslash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The backslash is being used as an escape character to ensure that the `0` which follows is being interpreted as ASCII 0 (0x00 hex) instead of the character `'0'` (ASCII 48 or 0x38 hex).

Comment: Awesome thanks for the terminology 'escape character' I found some good tutorials on escape sequences now so it's all a lot clearer. thanks again.